# Transaction doesnt get confirmed

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I use a blockchain wallet, and I tried to transfer some bitcoin from my blockchain wallet to my paxfull wallet, but its been stuck for like 3 days now. I used the recommended fee, I don't know why it takes so long.

Transaction: https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/731f8f345f008a0d5f777bc92752603bf7ef5360d6963efd2a08f8f81de2a634/

Today I looked up the transaction again, and the 'received time' restarted - its only 17 hrs now even though its been three days already. Anyone knows whats up with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the transaction could take a long time because the fee you paid is to small. Also, you can try to bump the fee through your wallet.